# Request Denied forever - request gpu quota increase in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, gae-quotas

I try and google does not accept request to increase the quota of in instance free Google Cloud ...someone could tell them what to do to accept and approve? thank...   how do I pay normal and get used and if you know one that offers VPS the same service? Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but... if it's about requesting a quota increase for your google cloud account, that's a customer service issue, and not something to be solved here. Unfortunately, a support issue is off-topic (assuming that's what you're asking).

Comment: sorry, but only request help...

Answer (score 6):

Quota increases are not available for free accounts at the moment. You can upgrade to the paid service by logging into your [Google Cloud Console](http://cloud.google.com/) as the Owner.

Then click “Upgrade my account” from the top of any page once logged in to upgrade the account from the free trial.

Once the account is upgraded, quota increases are then requested from the "Quotas" page. You can reference this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) for more detailed information and steps on requesting quota increases.

This will file a case with the Cloud Engine support team to process the request and it can take 24-48 hours for them to respond to you.

Prior to making any requests, I would also suggest reading through this [article](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#limitations)  to ensure you are as informed as possible prior to making any changes to the billing for your account.

Comment: Just started a trial and upgraded my account to request a GPU to utilize Deep Learning/PYTorch etc in a VM and it was DENIED without explanation.... As if... and to be honest this was a research project for a possible large scale deployment for a major corporation. Things like this make me always favor LAN deployments when possible.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was also working on the GCP cloud computing feature and I discovered that the rejection e-mail has a note that  `Until Billing account has additional history`. I guess the billing account must be tested before being assigned a GPU.

Comment: I have had the same issue. Never got around it. They ask to use other resources and create a billing history. However, why should anyone try to use something else if I do not need it.

Comment: @vermachint I currently switched to AWS cloud computing. They provide stable services. Consider using them, since my experience on GCP was very annoying and unpleasant.

Comment: Even after getting access to the GPUs, we often get rejected when connecting to them saying that there is no available resource.

Comment: Have been using AWS spot instances for now. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me too. They would reject all my requests and I was just asking an increase from 0 to 1. If you happen to have an edu email, you can try using that. When I switched to my edu email, my request got approved on the first try.